# Как поменять элемент в списке?

Tags: python, list

У меня список с маленькими списками в нем. Мне нужно поменять во всех маленьких списках элемент ADJF на ADJ.

Скажите, пожалуйста, как это можно сделать?

```
result = [['появление', 'NOUN'], ['оон', 'NOUN'], ['быть', 'VERB'], ['обусловить', 'PRTS'], ['целый', 'ADJF'], ['рядом', 'ADVB']]

for tt in result:
    list_B = [word if word != 'ADJF' else 'ADJ' for word in tt]
```

Но вообще ничего не получается

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если заменять прямо в том же списке:

```
for i in range(len(result)):
    if result[i][1] == 'ADJF':
        result[i][1] = 'ADJ'
```

Если надо создать новый:

```
list_B = [[a,'ADJ'] if b == 'ADJF' else [a,b] for a,b in result]
```

Comment: У меня помимо замены еще появляется что-то ['целый', 'ADJ', '', '', '']

Comment: @irina2020 Ни один из предложенных вариантов на вашем списке из вопроса такого результата не даст.

Comment: Да, вы правы. Не досмотрела

Answer (score -1):

с этой задачкой также может справиться `pandas` :

```
import pandas as pd

list_b = pd.DataFrame(result).replace('ADJF','ADJ').values.tolist()
```

результат:

```
[['появление', 'NOUN'],
 ['оон', 'NOUN'],
 ['быть', 'VERB'],
 ['обусловить', 'PRTS'],
 ['целый', 'ADJ'],
 ['рядом', 'ADVB']]
```